# Hibernate 5 > 6: DiscriminatorColumn of type Enum

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, hibernate-mapping

In migration from hibernate 5.* to 6.* there seems to be an issue that I've not been able to navigate. In hibernate 5.* I have used enumerations for the discriminator-type. This worked very well until this migration effort.

The following scenario:

```kotlin
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
    property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = GenericAction::class, name = "generic"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BreakAction::class, name = "break")
)
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
class Action (

    @Column(name = "type", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var type: ActionType = ActionType.GENERIC, //GENERIC, BREAK
....
)
```

```kotlin
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("GENERIC")
class GenericAction (
... 
): Action(ActionType.GENERIC)
```

```kotlin
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("BREAK")
class BreakAction (
... 
): Action(ActionType.BREAK)
```

This worked. It would save either `'GENERIC'` or `'BREAK'` in the database and create the correct polymorphic sub-type when fetched.

In hibernate 6.* not anymore. The issue I have found is that it tries to compare a `String` with the `ActionType` (which obviously does not work).

Tried the following:

1. `@DiscriminatorFormula`, this however fails whenever a `.createNativeQuery` is used.
2. Not using an Enum, this however creates issues at our JSON serialiser/deserialiser level as those same `@JsonProperty` conversions cannot be done
3. Tried `@Converter` on the `type` field
4. Dug through the sourcecode to see if I could inject/override or manipulate that Enum/String comparison in any way.

When converting everything to strings, it works to store/fetch data, it however does not allow for the original json-conversion. No matter which way I look, the changes on already existing data would be massive.